# How to read a web page using Bean shell in JMeter?

Tags: beanshell

Use Bean Shell sampler to hit simple [Google search](http://www.google.co.in/search?q=mysql), do I need a code for this?

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler, however if for some reason you need to do it in Beanshell here is the example script:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://google.com");
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
String responseCode = String.valueOf(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
String responseCode = String.valueOf(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
return responseString;
```

See the following reference material:

- [HttpClient Quick Start](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/quickstart.html)
- [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell)