# JMeter how to authenticate login with two passwords

Tags: jmeter

I am creating a jmeter scritp and the scnerio where i am struck is as follows:
First Try login to an application with Password 1, if login fails then try with password 2, if login fails with password2 aswell then the result should be fail otherwise pass. 
I have created a HTTP request and Password1, password2 are user defined variables.

Comment: when you submit the wrong password, does server return 403 error code? or 200 success code with an error message in the body of HTML? your design depends on it.

Comment: @Naveen When we submit wrong password it returns 200 success code with an error message in body. I have used regEx Extractor to get the error message and have stored it in a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Have two requests Req_1 and Req_2 and configure them with 'login' action one with each password. Use '*Regular Expression Extractor*' or other to parse the response to Req_1 and use 'If Controller' to see if it passed or not and submit Req_2 only if Req_1 login fails.

Comment: I am doing the same. I have used Regular Expression Extractor in Req_1 and stored the pass or failed status in a reference variable named 'StatusCode'. Then used if controller to see if it passed or not and then submit Req_2 only if Req_1 fails. This is wokring fine.

Answer (score 0):

Add BeanShell Sampler to the Test Plan and add the following code (working code for the given website):

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;


HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://httpbin.org/post");
List nvps = new ArrayList();
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "vip"));
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "secret"));
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
String responseCode = String.valueOf(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

String errorMessage = "secret";

if(responseString.contains(errorMessage)){
    log.info("first time failed");
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://httpbin.org/post");
    List nvps = new ArrayList();
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "vip"));
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "secret"));
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps));
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
    String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    String responseCode = String.valueOf(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
    if(responseString.contains(errorMessage)){
        log.info("second time failed");
        IsSuccess = false;
        ResponseCode = "403";
        ResponseMessage = "Login failed with both the passwords";   
    }
}
return responseString;
```

Add above script to "Script" text area in the BeanShell sampler.

Image reference:
[image]

**Note: replace the URL, username, password and error message as per your requirements. Add any headers if crucial.**

If you want to use HTTP Sampler, follow the process as suggested by @SaiMatam.

1. Add **If controller**, compare whether the error message is received (write condition in Condition field).
2. `Keep the same sampler (change only the password) inside If Controller`. this sampler would get execute only if the condition is satisfied.
3. Add **Response Assertion** for the sampler in If Controller. `Add the error message in "Pattern to test" field`. `select "Not" checkbox in "Pattern Matching Rules"`. This will make sure that, if the error message is received, the second request is marked as FAIL by JMeter (we are checking that the response should not contain the given string/pattern), otherwise will mark it as PASS.

References:

1. http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller
2. http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion

Comment: @Sai Doing the same. I have used Regular Expression Extractor in Req_1 and stored the pass or failed status in a reference variable named 'StatusCode'. Then used if controller to see if Req_1 passed or not and then submit Req_2 only if Req_1 fails. This is wokring fine, but what i want is in view Results tree listner, there should be just one login request  which should be either pass or fail. And It should be pass if either of the passwords work. I am not familier with Beanshell and JSR223 post post processors and was wondering if it is possible using these. I know core java.

Comment: you can try with BeanShell Sampler and write java code to send HTTP Post request using HTTPClient libraries. I'll post the answer once done.

Comment: reference for building GET request using BeanShell sampler is here, http://stackoverflow.com/a/36398252/2575259. you can build on that.

Comment: I have tried it but I am unable to create a HTTP post request where we can try login to an application with two different passwords. I will keep on trying and will be waiting for you answer :)

Comment: First, build one HTTP Post request for login and send. https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/quickstart.html, then you can resend the request by changing the password.

Comment: updated the answer. try it out. it is a practical example. you can directly copy and run the code which works for the given website.

Comment: The code posted by you worked after a bit of modification. Thanks :)

Comment: good to see it solved your problem. As I said, modification was must to suit your needs :)